# Web API - how to have custom display name for model validation properties?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-validation

If I have an `ApiController` which has a post method which consumes a model which has data annotations for validation, how do I customize the name displayed for the validation errors? I don't really want to override the entire error message, but I do need the property in the error to be something other than the name of the property on the model type.

I've tried things like DisplayNameAttribute and DisplayAttribute, but those don't seem to apply for this.

Comment: Is this for displaying the error on the client? Can you post some code showing what you are currently displaying

Comment: I had no custom code at this point, just a model with some properties that had [Required] and [Range] attributes. It displays the property name as it appears in .net, but I need it to display the property name in snake case because our service contract is in snake case (using a property name resolver for the json serializer). It's strange to throw validation errors like "ProperyName is invalid" when your contract is "property_name". That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found for this was based on the following:
https://gist.github.com/benfoster/4016852

You have to create your own validator provider (as shown in link), and your own validator which will set up a `ValidationContext` with the proper displayName such that

`validationContext.DisplayName = displayNameMappingFunction(metadata.GetDisplayName());`

You then need to register the validator provider globally by using GlobalConfiguration.Services, or you need to create an `IControllerConfigurationAttribute` which will configure it just for one controller.

You do `config.Services.Replace(typeof(ModelValidatorProvider), new CustomDisplayNameProvider()`